# selfbuilt pc shuts down and restarts. 1 long and 2 short beeps

Tags: power-supply, hardware-failure, gpu, desktop-computer

I have built a new pc and I almost finished. When I turn the computer on I starts up but then shuts down again.

The beeps I'm getting is 1 long and 2 short which I think is the video card or something, which i have reinstalled (it may be just 2 beeps aswell. 1 long beep when starts 2 when it shuts down.) The beeps are very quiet.

After it has shut down it will start itself again many times until I have to switch off the PSU. 
I have tried reinstalling the GPU's as said and the RAM. If you need any info on what parts I have just tell me.

I have also tried another pair of RAM sticks I had lying around, but I still get the same error so I don't know if the problem is the RAM.

Comment: what happens without the ram? different beeps? or the same problem?  Do you have another PSU to try?

Comment: Yes, super different beeps. theres 3 long very loud beeps, but the computer doesnt turn off.

Comment: ok so keep RAM in. Have you got the minimum in there? So, does the motherboard has its own HDMI or VGA connector?  have you tried without any video card in there?

Comment: Okay so I have taken out the two graphic cards and used the hdmi port in the motherboard, but It still makes 1 long beep and 2 short beeps and shuts down. I also have 16 GB RAM

Comment: Suspects are psu or mbrd. do you have another psu to try.  A spare psu is key when troubleshooting, perhaps you can use one from another comp if you don't have a spare readily aavailable

Comment: No, I currently don't have a second PSU. It was suggested that there may be some problem with the motherboard, but shouldn't it then beep accordingly? I really don't want dissemble all the parts.

Comment: I havent dealt with beeps that much.. as swapping parts works for diagnosing, and few disassemble a motherboard e.g. soldering iron(I tried years ago even the electrician I asked wouldn't touch a motherboard! - these days even in his work they swap parts).  If you really want to use the beep codes that's not a bad path to take given the lack of an easily available psu, but give info.. motherobard model. BIOS make and version, so we may be able to find the beep code manual for it.

Comment: The motherboard is a MSI Z97 Gaming 7 and the BIOS is an Award BIOS

Comment: looking at this page of Award BIOS beep codes. 1 long and 2 shorts indicates a video adaptor problem.    http://www.bioscentral.com/beepcodes/awardbeep.htm    You could try the MSI forum in the section for AMD motherboards https://forum-en.msi.com/index.php?board=24.0    maybe they have some ideas

Answer (score 0):

You should check your BIOS manufacturer's beep code index in the mainboard documentation.

Your description indicates a video adapter problem. Your video card could be misplaced or maybe your power supply isn't powerful enough to energize it.

[Source](http://www.computerhope.com/beep.htm)
**added by barlop**
The link the answerer gave above is a page from the computerhope site which lists beep codes, and his beep code of one long and two short, indicates a video error as indicated by the description on that page for his (Award) BIOS.

Comment: I have two MSI 970 gtx and a Corsair HX850 850 w PSU. I have tried removing both GPU's and doing it again. Then one GPU and just trying that in different places, but still the same error. Does that mean bth my GPU's are f**ked?

Comment: Do you connect the external power connectors on the graphics card? What's the make and model of your motherboard?

Comment: I have tried using the external power connector on the graphics card, but still the same error. My Motherboard is the MSI Z97 gaming 7.

Comment: -1 your answer is badly written. You say his description indicates a video adapter problem, you don't say what aspect of his description indicates it. Your first sentence says he should check his BIOS manufacturer's beep code index, which suggests that perhaps you haven't, but looking at the end of your post you write "source" and looking at it, it says beep codes. You give no indication of precisely what is found at that link you label "Source" at the end of your post. So I have added to your post making the point that the beep code he got indicates a video error, as stated by your link.